# Openlayers features clear method

Tags: openlayers, layers, vector, features, data-source

I want to clear the features in a vector layer source , I have tried

```
features.getFeatures().clear();
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this documentation page from Openlayers [`ol.source.Vector`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#clear)

You could include this method as such:

`vectorSource.clear`